# How to get number between special character in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Can you help to get below output in oracle

```
File_20170902_Name.txt
File200_Name_20170902_1.txt
File400_20170902_Name_1.txt
File1_name_20170902.txt
```

I am expecting output like

```
20170902
20170902
20170902
20170902
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250440/oracle-find-the-largest-number-within-one-string

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the  8 digit numbers in your filenames are dates and are preceded by a `_` and followed by an `_` or `.txt`, you may use

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(files,'_(\d{8})(_|.txt)',1,1,NULL,1) as dt FROM t;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68479/4)

> But some time number character will change like 6 (YYMMDD) character

This will match a sequence of  6 to 8 characters between `_` or `_` and `.txt`

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(files,'_((\d{6,8}))(_|)',1,1,NULL,1)
```

[**Demo2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3486a3/2)

But, This isn't a comprehensive regex to match dates. i.e it could match digits like `20189999` or `180000` if they are part of filename. if you want to detect only dates, then you may have to combine them with  methods specified here: [Valid Date Checks in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14702163/7998591)

Comment: Thanks kaushik. But some time number character will change like 6 (YYMMDD) character. Have any idea to handle this situation?

Comment: this query give below result.

select REGEXP_SUBSTR('File_20170902_Name.txt','_((\d{6}|\d{8}))(_|)',1,1,NULL,1) from dual;

O/P:
201709

But my expectation is "20170902".

Thanks!!

Comment: @user3444185 : Check now i've modified it

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c361c/4

```
select
 regexp_replace(str,'.*(\d{8}).*','\1') as x
from table1

|        X |
|----------|
| 20170902 |
| 20170902 |
| 20170902 |
| 20170902 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create table tst (x varchar2(30));
insert into tst values ('File_20170902_Name.txt');
insert into tst values ('File200_Name_20170902_1.txt');
insert into tst values ('File400_20170902_Name_1.txt');
insert into tst values ('File1_name_20170902.txt');

Select x,       
      case 
          when substr(x, REGEXP_INSTR(x, '[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]') + 1, 1) between chr(48) and chr(57) Then 
            substr(x, REGEXP_INSTR(x, '[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]') + 1, REGEXP_INSTR(x, '[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]', 1, 2) - REGEXP_INSTR(x, '[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]') - 1) 
          else substr(x, REGEXP_INSTR(x, '[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]', 1, 2) + 1, REGEXP_INSTR(x, '[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]', 1, 3) - REGEXP_INSTR(x, '[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]', 1, 2) - 1) 
      end as t      
From tst
```

Note: this query wont support if the number start after more than 2 special character like File_name_test_20170902.txt

Answer (score 0):

The following both work about the same - the use a regular expression to make the basic selection, then make use of either a second call to `REGEXP_SUBSTR` or use "normal" string functions to get rid of the delimiters. I prefer the nested calls to `REGEXP_SUBSTR` over the use of `TRANSLATE` or `REPLACE` but you can take your pick:

Nested calls to `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
WITH cteFiles AS (SELECT 'File_20170902_Name.txt' AS FILENAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'File200_Name_20170902_1.txt' AS FILENAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'File400_20170902_Name_1.txt' AS FILENAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'File1_name_20170902.txt' AS FILENAME FROM DUAL)
SELECT FILENAME, REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(FILENAME, '_[0-9]+[_.]'), '[^_.]+') AS FINAL_NUMS
  FROM cteFiles;
```

Using `REPLACE`:

```
WITH cteFiles AS (SELECT 'File_20170902_Name.txt' AS FILENAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'File200_Name_20170902_1.txt' AS FILENAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'File400_20170902_Name_1.txt' AS FILENAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'File1_name_20170902.txt' AS FILENAME FROM DUAL)
SELECT FILENAME, REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(FILENAME, '_[0-9]+[_.]'), '_', NULL), '.', NULL) AS FINAL_NUMS
  FROM cteFiles;
```

Using `TRANSLATE`:

```
WITH cteFiles AS (SELECT 'File_20170902_Name.txt' AS FILENAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'File200_Name_20170902_1.txt' AS FILENAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'File400_20170902_Name_1.txt' AS FILENAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'File1_name_20170902.txt' AS FILENAME FROM DUAL)
SELECT FILENAME, TRANSLATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(FILENAME, '_[0-9]+[_.]'), '0123456789_.', '0123456789') AS FINAL_NUMS
  FROM cteFiles;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53d64e/52)

Best of luck.